# why the ESP is bigger than EBP for python in my 32bit server?

Tags: python, assembly, x86

I use gdb to debug my program. The output like this, I break it at `Python/ceval.c:1071`

```
(gdb) info reg
eax            0x7d     125
ecx            0x29     41
edx            0x8a44e04        144985604
ebx            0xce4518 13518104
esp            0xbfb24d10       0xbfb24d10
ebp            0xb7d72bed       0xb7d72bed
esi            0x8a563e4        145056740
edi            0x8a56294        145056404
eip            0xc400f8 0xc400f8 <PyEval_EvalFrameEx+936>
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
(gdb)
```

so I want to know why esp is bigger than ebp?
some info,

```
Linux foxyfont2.uc.local 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:43 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux  
gcc 版本 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `ebp` is sometimes used as frame pointer it is nevertheless just another general purpose register. If it's not used as a frame pointer, its value can be anything. You might also be seeing leftover value from a previous use.

Comment: This is especially true if a C program is compiled with `-fomit-frame-ponter` (the default since gcc 4.6).

Comment: so what's the reason lead to ebp not used as a frame pointer? I written another c program just compiled by -g -o always used as a frame pointer

Comment: The reason is that in 32 bit mode you can address directly relative to `esp` so you don't usually need a frame pointer. For debugging you have explicit debug information which works fine without a frame pointer too. x86 doesn't have very many registers, so using `ebp` as another GPR allows better optimization.

Comment: ok, thanks very much. I want to get the function params by EBP, for example EBP+4 as the first param, but in this case I can not get it, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Upon entry into the function, the arguments start at `ESP+4`.